# vertically center a div and keep text right for a map legend

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a legend for a map but I have some trouble when title is too long...

What I'm looking for is a vertically center `img` & `.legend-block`, and all the text right of them (looking like the current 3rd legend)

I try to use `vertical-align:middle` in `.remove-btn` & `.legend-block` but it doesn't do anything...

http://jsfiddle.net/mf44gxqv/5/

```css
#chart-legend {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: black 1px solid;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.legend-value {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.legend-block {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: #bbb solid 1px;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
.remove-btn {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart-legend" class="panel-body">
  <div class="legend-value">
    <img class="remove-btn" src="/images/remove.png" alt="rmv" />
    <div class="legend-block" style="background-color: rgb(75, 178, 197);"></div>
    hello
  </div>
  <div class="legend-value">
    <img class="remove-btn" src="/images/remove.png" alt="rmv" />
    <div class="legend-block" style="background-color: rgb(234, 162, 40);"></div>
    I'm too long so I go where I should not hehe I'm shuch a bad legend
  </div>
  <div class="legend-value">
    <img class="remove-btn" src="/images/remove.png" alt="rmv" />
    <div class="legend-block" style="background-color: rgb(197, 180, 127);"></div>
    It's a trap cause I'm too short</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is flexbox an option? See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq8mpedn/)

Comment: the alignment and text looks good to me, but why some "legend-block" became shorter ?

Comment: I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq8mpedn/1/). To fix that issue I changed the `width` of the `.legend-block` to `min-width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (if you can use it in your project)

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq8mpedn/3/).

I added the following styles:

```
.legend-value {
    margin-bottom:15px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Then added `min-width`'s to `.legend-block` and `.remove-btn`

Comment: You made that look easy :p Gonna have to read up a little more about flexbox. What is the deal with the first legend appearing slightly offset to the others here?

Comment: I don't know if I'd use flexbox for simple problem like this. I kinda imagine flexbox in an application context, I think plain css is efficient and works in IE8 also. What do you think ?

Comment: @YannChabot I usually try and support the forward thinking approach and use flexbox whenever I can because I believe it will be the standard in the future. Flexbox is more configurable with less code which makes it way easier to maintain. Flexbox already has decent support (92.97% support - see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)), and if my project calls for IE8 support I can still use the `display:table-cell` approach mentioned below by using IE conditional statements to load CSS overrides wherever flexbox is used.

Comment: @Kinburn101 The first `<img>` is rendering longer than the `min-width:40px;`, whereas the other two are not so they are 40px and the first is like 43px or something. To fix this you can add `width:40px;` alongside the `min-width:40px;` and it will no longer be offset. In the real world I'm sure he wouldn't have broken img's there.

Comment: @zgood Nice! Just wasn't sure if that was a common happening when using flexbox.

Comment: @zgood I agree with you in a way, I just hate that it's IE9 incompatible I believe it's still used alot. But you're right, I may consider using it in the future since table are pretty heavy and I believe it's a "hacky" way to have vertical align. To be continued eheh

Answer (score 1):

I did an example with your fiddle, the best is to add a "wrapper" width a vertical align each place like this :

add this CSS:

```
 .valign{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and then the HTML (did it only for the orange one)

```
<div class="legend-value">
    <div class="valign">
        <img class="remove-btn" src="/images/remove.png" alt="rmv"/>     
    </div>
    <div class="valign">
        <div class="legend-block" style="background-color: rgb(234, 162, 40);"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="valign">
        I'm too long so I go where I should not hehe I'm shuch a bad 
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mf44gxqv/6/

The "table-cell" is very useful for vertical align.

Here is additionnal suggestion for vertical align: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text in a div. Then use `display: inline-block` with `vertical-align: middle` to line them up. You will also need to specify a width to the blocks as `inline-block` containers will stretch to its contents, breaking the `inline`.

```css
#chart-legend {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: black 1px solid;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.legend-value {
  margin-bottom: 15px;

}
.legend-block {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: #bbb solid 1px;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.legend-text {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.remove-btn {
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart-legend" class="panel-body">
  <div class="legend-value">
    <img class="remove-btn" src="/images/remove.png" alt="rmv" />
    <div class="legend-block" style="background-color: rgb(75, 178, 197);"></div>
    <div class="legend-text">hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="legend-value">
    <img class="remove-btn" src="/images/remove.png" alt="rmv" />
    <div class="legend-block" style="background-color: rgb(234, 162, 40);"></div>
    <div class="legend-text">I'm too long so I go where I should not hehe I'm shuch a bad legend</div>
  </div>
  <div class="legend-value">
    <img class="remove-btn" src="/images/remove.png" alt="rmv" />
    <div class="legend-block" style="background-color: rgb(197, 180, 127);"></div>
    <div class="legend-text">It's a trap cause I'm too short</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just messing around with this and this is what happened...

CSS, I added a new class, gave it a width, and aligned the text.

```
#chart-legend {
width: 250px;
padding: 10px;
border: black 1px solid;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
}
.legend-value {
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.legend-block {
width: 40px;
height: 20px;
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
border: #bbb solid 1px;
background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
.remove-btn {
float: left;
height: 20px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
.text-block {
display:block;
text-align:right;
width:25vw;
}
```

HTML, I put your text in a div.

```
<div id="chart-legend" class="panel-body">
<div class="legend-value">
<img class="remove-btn" src="/images/remove.png" alt="rmv" />
<div class="legend-block" style="background-color: rgb(75, 178, 197);">   </div>
<div class="text-block">hello</div>
</div>
<div class="legend-value">
<img class="remove-btn" src="/images/remove.png" alt="rmv" />
<div class="legend-block" style="background-color: rgb(234, 162, 40);"></div>
<div class="text-block">I'm too long so I go where I should not hehe I'm shuch a bad legend</div>
</div>
<div class="legend-value">
<img class="remove-btn" src="/images/remove.png" alt="rmv" />
<div class="legend-block" style="background-color: rgb(197, 180, 127);"> </div>
<div class="text-block">It's a trap cause I'm too short</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot of extra work but is this what you mean? you can change the vertical alignment in any way you would like. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mf44gxqv/7/)

HTML:

```
<div id="chart-legend" class="panel-body">
<div class="legend-item">
    <div class="legend-value">
        <img class="remove-btn" src="/images/remove.png" alt="rmv" />
    </div>
    <div class="legend-block">
        <div class="block" style="background-color: rgb(75, 178, 197);">    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="legend-text">hello</div>
</div>
<div class="legend-item">
    <div class="legend-value">
        <img class="remove-btn" src="/images/remove.png" alt="rmv" />
    </div>
    <div class="legend-block">
        <div class="block" style="background-color: rgb(234, 162, 40);">    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="legend-text">I'm too long so I go where I should not hehe I'm shuch a bad legend</div>
</div>
<div class="legend-item">
    <div class="legend-value">
        <img class="remove-btn" src="/images/remove.png" alt="rmv" />
    </div>
    <div class="legend-block">
        <div class="block" style="background-color: rgb(197, 180, 127);">    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="legend-text">It's a trap cause I'm too short</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#chart-legend {
width:200px;
padding:10px;
border:black 1px solid;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
}
.legend-item {
display:table;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.legend-value {
width:55px;
display:table-cell;
margin-bottom:15px;
vertical-align:top;
}
.legend-text {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:top;
}
.block {
height:20px;
width:40px;
border:#bbb solid 1px;
}
.legend-block {
width:55px;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:top;
} 
.remove-btn {
float:left;
height:20px;
margin-right:10px;
}
```